# What is the purpose of a license for open-source or free-software?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I want to understand these from the very beginning. Say I've written some library in some language, and uploaded them to [github.com](https://github.com/) as public repository. Now anyone can see and *use* them. I cannot stop them from *using* it, while allowing them to *see* the code only, as anybody who can *see*, can also *use* it.

My question is, what is the purpose of a license for such code? Does it stop them from *using* it? Or if they can still use it, does it (the license) *benefit me*  in any way? If yes, in what ways?

If I don't use any license for my source-code, is that a bad idea? To put it differently, would I regret in future if I dont use any license for my source-code which I release to the public?

What determines whether should I use any license or not? And on what basis should I choose a *particular* license for my code? How should I make *any decision* regarding licensing?

Please help me understand these things.

Comment: Whatever you create is yours. Nobody can use it. If you want to give it to the world you need to clearly state that. So, you use a license (or invent your own). 
I wrote here a summary of the most used license: https://GabrielMoraru.com/software-licenses-are-complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, what is the purpose of a license for such code?

The purpose of a license is that you have a document where it is written down which rights you *grant* with your copyrightable work (software can fall under copyright).

This helps users of your software to understand which rights they have with the software.

A *Free Software License* allows users to **use**, **study**, **share** and **improve** your software. This is the same for those *Approved Licenses* listed on the website of the *Open Source Initiative*.

So without a license you do not give many rights. A license clarifies which rights are granted. This is the first benefit for you: Users of your software don't need to ask you first.

> Does it stop them from using it?

No, a license is not stopping from using it. At least normally not. A license *grants* the rights needed to make use of the software therefore its actually the opposite.

> Or if they can still use it, does it (the license) benefit me in any way?

What do you mean by still use it? They can use the software if you provide a (known) software license. The benefit for you is that you tell so it's clear what you give.

> If yes, in what ways?

For example by clarifying that you provide the software AS-IS without warranties of some kind. If you look into the licenses you find a passage about exactly that.

> If I don't use any license for my source-code, is that a bad idea? To put it differently, would I regret in future if I don't use any license for my source-code which I release to the public?

Yes, this is generally a bad idea because you more or less do not tell your users which rights they've got with the software. That can have negative influence on usage patterns and contribution patterns. That's something you might regret in the future.

See as well:

- [Can I use the code in a Github project which does not have a license specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521080/can-i-use-the-code-in-a-github-project-which-does-not-have-a-license-specified)

This is a good book available online which goes through a lot of stuff step-by-step, for example [Choosing a License and Applying It](http://producingoss.com/en/license-quickstart.html) - The book is called [Producing Open Source Software How to Run a Successful Free Software Project by Karl Fogel](http://producingoss.com/).

And this is one of the best essays that basically tells nearly *everything*: [Make Your Open Source Software GPL-Compatible. Or Else.](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/gpl-compatible.html) by David A. Wheeler Released 2002-05-06, revised 2013-01-18 - it has a lot of very good links as well.

Comment: I've one last question : if I decide to use a license say, Boost Software License or BSD, do I need to take permission from anyone before using it? Or just copying the license wordings and pasting it to my source file is enough (without taking permission)? In other words, is there any license for such licenses? Well, it is getting recursive!

Comment: Both [`BSL-1.0` Boost Software License 1.0](http://spdx.org/licenses/BSL-1.0) nor [`BSD-2-Clause` BSD 2-clause "Simplified" License](http://spdx.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause) do not require any permissions to use. Insert your name / copyright where the placeholders are and you should be fine. BSD is better known which is a benefit, but both are a lax, permissive non-copyleft free software license, compatible with the GNU GPL.

Comment: This is a good book available online which goes through a lot of stuff step-by-step, for example [Choosing a License and Applying It](http://producingoss.com/en/license-quickstart.html) - The book is called [Producing Open Source Software How to Run a Successful Free Software Project by Karl Fogel](http://producingoss.com/)

Comment: And this is one of the best essays that basically tells nearly *everything*: [Make Your Open Source Software GPL-Compatible. Or Else. by David A. Wheeler Released 2002-05-06, revised 2013-01-18](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/gpl-compatible.html) - it has a lot of very good links as well.

Comment: I'm unable to decide which license should I use for my github libraries. Can I use Boost Software License? Or it is restricted  to Boost Libraries only?

Comment: You on your own can use any license you wish in general. In concrete Boost License does not look bad in my eyes, if you want a license without copyleft, you can take it. You need to add your copyright statement somewhere because the license text says it needs to be preserved. Good luck with your project!

Comment: What is copyleft? Also, could you please rephrase this *"You need to add your copyright statement somewhere because the license text says it needs to be preserved"*? I couldn't completely understand it. I've seen Boost source code which contains like like *"Copyright Pavol Droba 2002-2003"*. Do I need to write such lines in my source code also if I use BSL **(is this what you meant in the italic text I quoted)**?

Comment: copyleft is a specific kind of licese, see http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/ for an explanation. For a copyright line I suggest you take a look into the book by Fogel. The copyright of Boost is by Boost, so not fitting for your code which has you as copyright owner (if you wrote it your own).

Comment: If I use Boost License and write "Copyright Nawaz" in each source file, would that be okay?

Comment: yes. you can leave your copyright message where you see fit. I think Fogel describes that quite well. A copyright message can be *Copyright Nawaz 2013*  for example. You don't need to use your real name, you can take your artist-name in copyright.

Comment: Thanks for all the clarification. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Start by reading this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/04/pick-a-license-any-license.html

Summarized: all code is copyrighted by default, whether you state something or not. If one uses unlicensed code the owner (or heirs) can retroactively decide to sue you.

Comment: And how would I know who is using my code? That is impossible to know, don't you think so?

Comment: Do you care? :-) But yeah, it usually very hard to know, no matter the license. Note that a proper business/ethical person will not use your code if the license does not allow so.